# Using a spherecast to target the nearest gameobject with a specific tag by using a NavMesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, raycasting

I am trying to make a robot detect the nearest robot from it using a `SphereCast` and no matter what I do, it does not seem to work.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class BasicChaseScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public NavMeshAgent myrobo;
    public GameObject enemy;
    CharacterController charCtrl;
    public float distanceToObstacle = 0;

    public float roboheight;
    public float detectionrange;
    public float maxdistance;
    public LayerMask thing;
    public Vector3 DIR;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        charCtrl = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (enemy == null)
        {
            RaycastHit hit;

            Vector3 p1 = transform.position + charCtrl.center;


            // Cast a sphere wrapping character controller 10 meters forward
            // to see if it is about to hit anything.
            if (Physics.SphereCast(p1, charCtrl.height / 2, transform.forward, out hit, 10))
            {
                distanceToObstacle = hit.distance;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

I am trying to make it detect any robots near it with the tag Robot.

Comment: What kind of debug statements have you added? If you place them at the beginning and end of your code blocks, you should get a fair idea if the blocks you think are getting run are getting run.

Comment: Well, a spherecast is likely not the right tool for this job...

Comment: Don't know how to use Debug.log on raycasts, new to raycast in general, also, Draco, what would you recommend using?